# Connection to solana cluster using the ThinClient of the rust client library giving timeout error?

Tags: rust, solana-sdk, solana-client, solana-client-sdk

I am trying to connect to solana using the ThinClient provided by the solana client library:
https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/thin_client/struct.ThinClient.html

It requires a Rpc Address and a TPU address and a connection Cache.
The Rpc address seems to be working fine(since the rpc client functions are working),
however for the TPU address (I guess that's the problem since the error doesn't really tell much) gives a connection timeout error when I try to do something with it(like sending a transaction)

Here is the function where I am trying to send a transaction:

```
fn thinclientsendtransaction(program_id: Pubkey, payer: &Keypair){
let rpc_addr="127.0.0.1:8899".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
let tpu_addr="0.0.0.0:1027".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
let connectioncache=connection_cache::ConnectionCache::new(20000000);
let client=ThinClient::new(rpc_addr, tpu_addr, Arc::new(connectioncache));
let bankins=BankInstruction::Initialize;
let instruction = Instruction::new_with_borsh(
    program_id,
    &bankins,
    vec![],
);

let message = Message::new(
    &[instruction],
    Some(&payer.pubkey()),
);
let blockhash = client.rpc_client().get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();
let tx = Transaction::new(&[payer], message, blockhash);
let x=client.async_send_transaction(tx).unwrap();
//let x=client.get_account(&program_id).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}",x);
```

}

The full project can be found here:
https://github.com/Lioncat2002/SolanaProjectTest

Any help/pointers to the right direction will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the tpu address is most likely incorrect.  When you start your local validator, it should give the address, ie:

```
solana-test-validator
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠄ Initializing...
⠤ Initializing...
Identity: BLkdeSxX6tdW5nDUonhUbQERfxgAhdhsumricSxch6qz
Genesis Hash: FhmngVHsHijJRJrDMPp16EEf8nJrkbhj88JKYE11Xgnv
Version: 1.14.4
Shred Version: 39460
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
```

From that, you can see the shown TPU address in your example, which would be `"127.0.0.1:1027"` here. However, since the TPU uses the QUIC port now, you must add 6 to the shown port, which means that the proper address is `"127.0.0.1:1033"`.

Comment: Yup I had tried with the address 127.0.0.1:1027
but it still gave the same connection timeout error.

Comment: The port is typically generated randomly, so are you sure that you used the one that showed up when you started your local validator? It could be some other address

Comment: yeah I am absolutely sure.

Comment: Hm that's weird, as another test, can you try to deploy a program locally with the solana cli? ie `solana config set -ul` then `solana program deploy some_random_program.so`? If that works, then there's an issue with that code.  If it doesn't work, then there's an issue with the local networking

Comment: Yeah lemme try that out

Comment: I deployed the rust example on chain program. It does seem to be working fine

Comment: Oh, wait a second, this is going to sound silly, but can you try the port shown + 6? I think it might need to specify the QUIC port instead of the TPU port. So in my earlier example, you would do "127.0.0.1:1033"

Comment: That worked!
Thank You!!

Comment: That's great! I edited my answer to add the QUIC info, feel free to accept it if you want